# return n == 0 ? 0 : fib2(n, 0, 1) i can't find that?

Tags: c, recursion, fibonacci

```
unsigned long fib(unsigned int n)
{
  return n == 0 ? 0 : fib2(n, 0, 1);
}

unsigned long fib2(unsigned int n, unsigned long p0, unsigned long p1)
{
  return n == 1 ? p1 : fib2(n - 1, p1, p0 + p1);
}
```

i am trying to write fibonacci in single recursion and i found that code. but i first time see that

`return n == 0 ? 0 : fib2(n, 0, 1);`

code. what is `"?"` and `":"`, i can't find anything  about that.that is if?

Comment: Please do not alter the question in a way that changes the original completely. If you want to ask something else, ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

`? :` is ternary operator in C. It is like `if else` statement. The statement

```
 return exp1 ? exp2 : exp3;
```

returns `exp2` if `exp1` is true otherwise it will return `exp3`. It is equivalent to

```
if(exp1)  
    return exp2;  
else 
    return exp3;
```